# Python mutagen overwrite mp3 album cover

Tags: python, image, file, audio, mp3

I have a lot of mp3 files, most of them already with an album cover, now I want to use mutagen to update this cover art.

I have now run into a problem, apperantly mutagen sort of appends the new album art to the file instead of overwriting it, players then only see the first one and it looks to me as if it didn't work.

When I used ffmpeg to get rid of all tags from the file, my script worked just fine.

I either need to delete the existing coverart before adding a new one, or I need to tell mutagen to overwrite it, and I couldn't find any way to do that.

Using ffmpeg to get rid of the album art for all of my files and then running my script is not an option.

Here is my code so far:

```py
from mutagen.id3 import APIC, ID3
file = ID3("file.mp3")

with open("album.jpg", 'rb') as albumart:
    file.add(APIC(
        encoding=3,
        mime='image/jpeg',
        type=3, desc=u'Cover',
        data=albumart.read()
    ))

file.save(v2_version=3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
file = ID3("file.mp3") # Load the file
file.delall("APIC") # Delete every APIC tag (Cover art)
file.save() # Save the file
```